# Compare laravel query results

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Inside the `$get_user` and `$get_code` queries they both have a group_id.

I have dd(); them Both and made 100% sure.

the `$get_user` query has multiple group_id's and the `$get_code` only has one `group_id` which is equal to one of the `$get_user` group_id's.

The goal at the moment is to create a `group_id` match query.

Get the code that has a group ID equal to one of the `$get_user` group_id's

```
public function getCodesViewQr($code_id)
{
  $userid = Auth::id();
  $get_user = GroupUser::all()->where('user_id',$userid);
  $get_code = Code::all()->where('id',$code_id);

  $group_match = GroupUser::where('group_id', $get_code->group_id);

  $view['get_users'] = $get_user;
  $view['get_codes'] = $get_code;

  $view['group_matchs'] = $group_match;

  return view('codes.view_qr_code', $view);
}
```

The group match query does not work.  `$get_code->group_id` does not get the code group_id.

If there is a match then set `$match` equal to rue. else `$match` is False

```
$group_match = GroupUser::where('group_id', $get_code->group_id);
```

I'm using two Models `Code` and `GroupUser`

My `Code` table is like this :

-id

-group_id `(This is the only on important right now)`

-code_type

My `GroupUser` table is like this :

-id

-group_id `(This is the only on important right now)`

-user_id

-user_role

I have linked the Models

Inside my Code Model I have the relationship to GroupUser

```
public function group_user()
{
  return $this->belongsto('App\GroupUser');
}
```

And Inside my GroupUser Model I have the relationship to Code

```
public function code()
{
  return $this->belongsto('App\Code');
}
```

Inside My Code controller I have included my models.

```
use App\Code;
use App\GroupUser;
```

Comment: `GroupUser::all()->where('user_id',$userid);`. I think you want to use `GroupUser::where('user_id',$userid)->get();`

With your code you request all records from database, add them to a collection and add your constraints later with the `where()` method. This is ok for small results sets but it might be better to reduce the records on DB level.

Comment: Could you do `GroupUser::where('user_id',$userid)->pluck('group_id')` and dump the output?

Comment: cool will do it now.

Comment: If I dd that query I get ths error.  --  "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'dd' (T_STRING)"

Comment: Do you defined a relation between User and Group and Group and Code?

Comment: if I dump it I get the group_id's in an array :D

Comment: Collection {#219 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => 11
    1 => 12
    2 => 13
  ]
}

Comment: Yes. The relationship is between the Codes table and GroupUser table

Comment: Can you update your question and add the code of all relevant Models (User, GroupUser, Code and Coupon).

Comment: Sure I will do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys so I had some help from a guy I work with and this is the solution he came up with. We made a few adjustments. all the Databases and results stayed the same. we just changed the method we used to get the results.

I really appreciate all the help from @[linktoahref](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5808894/linktoahref)

```
    public function view_code($random)
    {
      $code = Code::where('random', $random)->first();
      $view['code'] = $code;

      if ($code->code_type == 1)
      {
        // Its a coupon
        if (!empty(Auth::user()))
        {
          // Someones is logged in
          $user = Auth::user();
          $view['user'] = $user;
          $user_groups = GroupUser::where('user_id',$user->id)->pluck('group_id')->toArray();

          if (in_array($code->group_id, $user_groups))
          {
            // The user is an admin of this code
            return view('view_codes.coupon_admin', $view);

          }else
            {
              // Save the code to that users account
              return view('view_codes.generic_code', $view);
            }
        }else
          {
          // Anon
          return view('view_codes.coupon_anon', $view);
          }
      }elseif ($code->code_type == 2)
        {
          // Voucher..
        }else
          {
            // We don't know how to deal with that code type
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$get_code = Code::find($code_id);

// Check if the code isn't null, else give a fallback to group_id
$group_id = 0;

if (! is_null($get_code)) {
    $group_id = $get_code->group_id;
}

$group_match = GroupUser::where('group_id', $group_id)
                        ->get();

$match = FALSE;

if ($group_match->count()) {
    $match = TRUE;
}
```